# .filter(...).then is not a function in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to `filter` an array inside `componentDidMount` and `then` `setState` on `propertyID` of the returned item

```
componentDidMount() {
  const pathname = "/path2";
  const properties = this.props.properties;
  properties
    .edges
    .filter(node => {
      return `/${node.slug}` === pathname;
    })
    .then(node =>
      this.setState({ propertyID: node.information.propertyID })
    );
}
```

but am receiving this error

> Uncaught TypeError: properties.filter(...).then is not a function
>       at ProxyComponent.componentDidMount

When `this.props.properties` is as

```
{
  "edges": [
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "121323",
        "slug": "path1",
        "information": {
          "propertyID": "property1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "332342",
        "slug": "path2",
        "information": {
          "propertyID": "property2"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "123234",
        "slug": "path3",
        "information": {
          "propertyID": "property3"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Array filter doesn't return a promise...

Comment: Filter does not return Promise and is not an async call. That's why you don't get .then from it

Comment: Save your filter Result in a variable and use setState then

Comment: Okay, thank you. I had tried that @NitishNarang as `const filteredProperty = properties.filter(node => '/${node.slug}' === pathname);` but if was not returning anything and I had read on another question that it could `return` a `promise`. By the downvotes and your comments I expect this was wrong. I expect my use in a variable is undefined because I have incorrectly read the `array`.

Comment: Well yes, `filter()` always returns a new, filtered array. It doesn't return a Promise. Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter ...Also, do you mind stating your expected output from this problem?

Comment: Realised your mistake @Darren. Added an answer. You can use filter without .then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the line of Filter as below and it will work. In Filter function, notice how I am using node object in { } notation

In your case "node" was representing entire object

```
{
      "node": {
        "id": "121323",
        "slug": "path1",
        "information": {
          "propertyID": "property1"
        }
      }
    }
```

But you needed "node" of this object that's why added {} in filter function.

Solution -

```js
var properties = {
  "edges": [
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "121323",
        "slug": "path1",
        "information": {
          "propertyID": "property1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "332342",
        "slug": "path2",
        "information": {
          "propertyID": "property2"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "123234",
        "slug": "path3",
        "information": {
          "propertyID": "property3"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

console.log(properties
    .edges
    .filter(({ node }) => `/${node.slug}` === '/path1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.filter does not return a promise. Change your code to this to make it runnable:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const pathname = "/path2";
  const properties = this.props.properties;
  const filteredArray = properties
    .edges
    .filter(node => {
      return `/${node.slug}` === pathname;
    });

  filteredArray.forEach((node) => {
    // Computed property, so each node gets set separately in state
    this.setState({ [node.information.propertyID]: node.information.propertyID })
  });
}
```

[Array.filter reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const pathname = '/path2';
  const properties = this.props.properties;

  const node = properties.edges.filter(node => {
    return `/${node.slug}` === pathname;
  });

  this.setState({ propertyID: node.information.propertyID });
}
```